# storing struct type in a list or dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, struct

I have existing legacy code in C# where we store struct type in a memlib type and then create 3 keys to access the memlib structs in a faster way. Please have a look at the below snapshot:

```
public struct gtBuildRecType : ICloneable
    {
        public double dParentLocCd; //   8 bytes : Key1
        public double dLocationCd; //   8 bytes : Key2
        public int lHierLevel; //   4 bytes : Key3
        public int lSequence;
        public int lDupChecked;
        public int nStatusInd;
    }
```

Memlib record and the 3 keys are defined like as following:

```
    static public Memlib<gtBuildRecType> gnBuildTable = null;
    static public Key<gtBuildRecType> gnBuildParentCdKey = null;
    static public Key<gtBuildRecType> gnBuildLocCdKey = null;
    static public Key<gtBuildRecType> gnBuildHierLevelKey = null;
```

Now, **gnBuildTable** Memlib can contain thousands of struct records and we can use any of the 3 keys i.e., **gnBuildParentCdKey, gnBuildLocCdKey, gnBuildHierLevelKey** for faster access. For example:

```
gtBuildRecType uTempRec = gtBuildRecType.CreateInstance();
MemLibStatus nReturn = gnBuildTable.ReadEqual(gnBuildParentCdKey, ref uTempRec);
```

This piece of code will immediately fill the **uTempRec** from **gnBuildTable** where the **gnBuildParentCdKey** matches a struct record in the **gnBuildTable** and then we can update the **uTempRec** accordingly and save the changes.

**NOW, My question is:**  I want to replace the Memlib with List or Dictionary. I would want to store these thousands of struct records in either List or Dictionary but How shall I implement the 3 keys approach with List or Dictionary, so that my search becomes even faster????. I started with List(Not using any key) but half way across i am facing issues to search for accurate struct record in the list.

I had initially tried a dictionary approach as well using single key but i ran into issues there as well.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: How are you storing the data?  It may just be better to keep storage as a struct and then create the dictionary after you read the file.

Comment: @jdweng Data is retrieved from the backend and each row returned is stored in struct and the struct in-turn is stored in Memlib.  Even creating the Dictionary leads to problem as the existing design has 3 keys and Dictionary will have maximum 1 key.

Comment: It would be more useful if the question described what you are actually trying to do, what you have tried, the result of that, and what you would expect. Currently you are describing how you are using a library, so it is difficult to answer without being familiar with that exact library.

Comment: I would leave everything alone and just add a dictionary to speed up the process.  You should have a List<gtBuildRecTyp> that you can use to create the dictionary.  So dictionary would be            List<gtBuildRecType> myList = new List<gtBuildRecType>();
            Dictionary<double, gtBuildRecType> dict = myList.GroupBy(x => x.dParentLocCd).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
If you have more than item per key then : Dictionary<double, List<gtBuildRecType>> dict = myList.GroupBy(x => x.dParentLocCd).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

Comment: I came across boost.multiindex component for C# which might make my tasks easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, To overcome this issue I could use multi-index 3rd party library or could also work through the DataTable. Make the fields of structs as the column in datatable.